# Are iterators guaranteed to mutate when incrementing and decrementing them?

Tags: c++, iterator

I'm trying to store a few `std::string:iterator`s in a `vector`, and iterate over them like so:

```
while (something) {
    for (auto& it : iterators) {
        do_things(*it++);
    }
}
```

This seems to work - the iterators in the `iterators` vector mutate their position when incremented. I do not reassign them in the vector, they're the same `iterator` objects throughout the program.

Is being mutable by incrementing and decrementing guaranteed about any iterator? Or is it safer to treat them as immutable objects and reassign them after changing them? E.g. `it = it++;`

Comment: "Is remembering one's current position guaranteed about any iterator?" - what else would be the purpose of an iterator? As long as you aren't invalidating any of the iterators by modifying the containers they point to, you're fine.

Comment: @cigien My bad, changed it to a `auto&`

Comment: @alterigel Some iterators cease to become dereferencable due to circumstances beyond mutation of the container. For example input iterators are not dereferencable once *any copy of them* has been advanced.

Comment: @AvivCohn Not sure why you're asking about immutability, because you are explicitly mutating the iterator via the `++` operator.

Comment: @alterigel Yeah the question wasn't clear enough, I've now clarified it. Of course the iterator remembers its position. What I meant was, are iterators guaranteed to mutate internally when incrementing, decrementing or adding to them? Or does this just happen to be a characteristic of the string iterator?

Comment: @AvivCohn If iterators didn't mutate internally when incrementing, then what would be the point of incrementing them? Indeed, your `for` loop relies on the mutability of the vector iterator.

Comment: @RaymondChen That's the question - is `++` guaranteed to also mutate the internal state of the iterator, or is it legal for an iterator to implement `++` by simply returning an advanced copy of itself?

Comment: You can create your own iterator which might do nothing for `++`.

Comment: The `++` pre-increment or post-increment will change the state of the iterator if anything will. Sometimes the iterator won't change, like if it is already at `end()` or as someone else mentioned, if it does not really point to anything and always returns the same value. But `it = it + 1` or `it += 1` or `++it` or `it++` should all result in identical internal states.

Comment: I think the key point is that `++` _is_ a mutation. I would severely question any class that had a `++` operator that didn't mutate as poorly designed.

Comment: `++` is not *guaranteed* to mutate the state, but it is permitted to. Certain iterators, like forward iterators, are pretty much forced to mutate, because an incremented forward iterator does not refer to the same object as a copy of it prior to increment. ("[Multipass guarantee](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ForwardIterator).")

Comment: Are you asking (in the current version of your question) if changing an iterator (via `++` or `--`) is guaranteed to change the iterator?

Comment: You say "... reassign them after changing them" so you already are saying that `++` changes the iterator. If you wanted to treat it as immutable, you would have written `it = it + 1` or `it = std::next(it)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are iterators specified to be stateful?

They are not "specified" as such, at least not explicitly. Iterators are specified in terms of what operations they support, and what behaviour those operations have.

Containing state is implicit in the abstract concept of what an iterator does, and it is very typical for iterators to conform to that abstract concept. Iterators are an abstraction of pointers. Pointers are stateful.

But it is also possible to define an iterator type that doesn't contain state. Such iterator will necessarily be quite simple. An example would be output iterator that always returns 42 when you indirect through it.

> is it safer to treat them as immutable objects and reassign them after changing them? E.g. `it = it++;`

No. Also if you change them, then you aren't treating them as immutable objects.